# extend() using underscore vs. backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, backbone.js, underscore.js

I know backbone is somewhat depending on underscore and jquery. Is there difference between the two lines below?

```
app.notifications = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);
```

**AND**

```
app.notifications  = Backbone.Events.extend({});
```

If they are **NOT** the same, how different?

Comment: pretty sure Backbone.Events.extend does not exist

Comment: 0.9.9 now allows you to extend Events http://backbonejs.org/?0-9-9#changelog

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Backbone.Events.extend does not exist, 
so I will refer to Backbone.Model instead.

`_.extend(target, mixin1, mixin2)` is going to copy properties into the target object

Backbone.Model.extend is going to `subclass` Backbone.Model basically make a constructor (function) whose prototype has your provided properties.  This will allow you to make instances of your new class

```
var Person = Backbone.Model.extend({name: 'yourName'});
var me = new Person();
alert(me.name);
```

while `_.extend` would fail

```
var Person = _.extend({name: 'yourName'}, Backbone.Model);
var me = new Person();  //error b/c Person is a regular object
alert(me.name);
```

In short Backbone.Model.extend creates a new constructor (function), while _.extend modifies an existing object;

```
var modified = {};
alert(modified === _.extend(modified, Backbone.Model)); //true
alert(modified === Backbone.Model.extend(modified)); //false
```