# Why does backbone use the _.extend() method throughout?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am curious in creating an MVC javascript framework for fun, and as a learning experience.

Inside backbone.js https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js the author uses underscore's `_.extend()` method to "extend" the backbone object.

Starting with the `Model` I am trying to figure out the benefit of this.

```
// Attach all inheritable methods to the Model prototype.
_.extend(Model.prototype, Events, {});
```

How does this work? `Model` is already defined before this, then the author wants to `Copy all of the properties in the source objects over to the destination object` http://underscorejs.org/#extend, he creates a whole bunch of methods inside to interact with the source model as a prototype?

Why not do

```
Backbone.Model.prototype.get = function() {
    return 'Do Get';
}

Backbone.Model.prototype.set = function() {
    return 'Do Set';
}
```

Or better yet use Es6? Is the below even the same as the above??

```
class Model extends Backbone {
  get() {
    return 'Do Get';
  }
  set() {
    return 'Do Set';
  }
}
```

Am I on the right path, or am I missing something here? Obviously he created this before es6 was a thing, but I am also curious to know if it could have been done.

My angle is do grasp his intentions and recreate the concept without an underscore dependancy.

Comment: you can "inherit" from multiple collections by extending each one, whereas tying it to the prototype creates a single association. it also lets you more easily edit the instance without affecting other code since the methods are own properties instead of actual prototype methods.

Comment: Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13105746/4759033)

Comment: The Events object here is a mixin... read about mixins...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[_.extend](http://underscorejs.org/#extend) is a classical method for safe merging of objects.

By safe I mean  that the first argument of `_.extend(obj1, obj2, ..., objN)` will get all enumerable properties of all objects, passed as arguments after it.

```
_.extend(Backbone.Model.prototype, {
  get: function() {
    return 'Do Get';
  }
}

// Is an equivalent of
Backbone.Model.prototype.get = function() {
    return 'Do Get';
}
```

> **Backbone.Events**
>
> *Events* is a module that can be mixed in to any object, giving the
>   object the ability to bind and trigger custom named events.

In other words, this object is a set of methods for custom event handling.
The reason why `Backbone.Model.prototype` is extended is explained in the following answer [JS - Why use Prototype?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8433493/2294657)

Talking of ES6, you have to remember, that `class` keyword only introduces a syntax sugar around old prototype inheritance for constructor functions.

```
// This will won't work, since you can't extend objects. It has to be a constructor.
class Model extends Backbone {
  ...
}
```

I will push it a bit further and say taht Backbone doesn't work that well with ES6 classes, see more in [Why Backbone.js and ES6 Classes Don't Mix](http://benmccormick.org/2015/04/07/es6-classes-and-backbone-js/).